# How to update Highcharts with multiple series via JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am struggling very much with updating my Highcharts line chart vis JSON (actually, JSONP). I just don't get the jQuery code to work with my data and the graph.

I have a (possible, could be formatted differently) response from my server side PHP like this:

```
    [{  "name": "France",
        "data": [[1960,520325],
                 [1961,548976],
                 [1962,585604],
                 ...
                ]
     },{"name": "Germany",
        "data": [[1960,62718],
                 [1961,83872],
                 [1962,99201],
                 ...
                ]
     },{"name": ...
```

The client side then looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            series: []
        };


        var url =  "http://xxx/jsonp_response.php?callback=?";


        $.getJSON(url, {selectedCountries: "France,Germany,Switzerland", type: "jsonp"})
        .done(function(data)
        {
            // Split the data string into "name" and "data"
            $.each(data, function(name, values)
            {
                var items = values.toString().split(",");

                //now, name is for category
                options.series[].name = name;


                $.each (items, function(year, value)
                {
                    // now, categories
                    options.xAxis.categories = year;

                    // now, values
                    options.series[].data = value;
                });
            });            

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        })
```

The thing is probably much easier than this. But I tried a lot of different approaches, many of whom I found here in the search, but in vain. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the statement from Sebastian, I reworked my PHP which generates the JSON as well as the client side, and it works perfectly. For others having the same issue, here is the correct code:

The JSON can be verified with [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com).

Server-side:

```
$values = array();
$values[] = array(2000,20);
$values[] = array(2001,10);
$values[] = array(2002,12);

$data[] = array("name" => "Germany", "data" => $values);    

unset($values);
$values[] = array(2000,8);
$values[] = array(2001,4);
$values[] = array(2002,10);

$data[] = array("name" => "France", "data" => $values); 

header("content-type: application/json"); 

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($data) . ')';
```

Client-side:

```
<body>

    <div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                series: [{}]
            };


            var url =  "http://xxx/jsonp_response.php?callback=?";


            $.getJSON(url, {selectedCountries: "Germany,France", type: "jsonp"})
                .done(function(data)
                {
                    options.series = data;
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                })
                .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) 
                {
                    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
                })
        });

    </script> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case when your json is validate (containse number values) you dont need to parse it and push values for categories etc. So refer your json to series object and run in chart.